# Excel file download doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I'm using a mysql db to excel script which converts entire table in db to a excel file. When i try to execute the file it doesn't download the excelfile, nor does it give any error. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "username"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "password";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "dbname";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "data"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "excelfilename";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Just naming a file *.xls does not magical make it an excel file

Comment: If you have to pretend that a csv file is an Excel file, at least use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to create it

Comment: As you're explicitly suppressing any errors related to the database, perhaps it's failing somewhere there; but have you checked your log files?

Comment: And if you do that, call a spade a spade, and declare it *.csv

Comment: Yes, i've checked the log. The script runs perfectly fine on localhost, but fails to run on server. I checked all the db details, they're correct too.